# Sequelize include an attribute from junction table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building a shop, where in the database i have orders and items. Here's the code for the models:

Item:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = require('./sequelize')
var Item = sequelize.define('item', {
  image: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  itemName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'item_name'
  },
  price: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

module.exports = Item
```

Order:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = require('./sequelize')
var Order = sequelize.define('order', {
  orderNumber: {
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
  },
  shop: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  location: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})

module.exports = Order
```

They are related through belongs to many:

```
Item.belongsToMany(Order, {through: OrderItem})
Order.belongsToMany(Item, {through: OrderItem})
```

The OrderItem has an additional field, 'count', which i need to return:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = require('./sequelize')

var OrderItem = sequelize.define('OrderItem', {
  count: Sequelize.INTEGER
})

module.exports = OrderItem
```

However, when i try to include the OrderItem model, it doesn't work. No errors, nothing. The query just doesn't return:

```
Order.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: userId
      },
      include: [{
        model: Item,
        include: [OrderItem]
      }]
    }).then(orders => {
      console.log(orders)
      res.status(200).json(orders)
    })
```

How to get what i need from sequeilize?

Comment: why you want to include OrderItem in the model Item. This is the third table and you can use that table to enter the value of the oderId and ItemId.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
  Order.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: userId
      },
      include: [{ model: Item, 
        as:'item', 
        through:{attributes:['count']} // this may not be needed
      }]
  }).then(orders => {
    console.log(orders)
    res.status(200).json(orders)
  })
```

Also, your models must have a right naming strategy. E.g. :

Item - must have itemId field instead of itemNumber,
Order - must have orderId as primary field

OrderItem's structure:

```
var OrderItem = sequelize.define('OrderItem', {
  orderId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  itemId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  count: Sequelize.INTEGER
})
```

Another one is to use direct names of related fields and models when you use belongsToMany()

More here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the OrderItem is already nested inside the Item object. However, this doesn't make a nice return format , so the question is still open.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is year later, but yet..

You can use the property `joinTableAttributes` to get a junction table fields .

for example :

```
Order.findAll({
  where: {
    userId: userId
  },
  joinTableAttributes: ['count'],
  include: [{
    model: Item,
  }]
}).then(orders => {
  console.log(orders)
  res.status(200).json(orders)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Graphql and I had the same problem with the formatting. I did a small map after getting the result.
For example:

```
  let orders = await Order.findAll({
    where: {
      userId: userId
    },
    include: [{ model: Item, 
      as:'item', 
      through:{attributes:['count']} 
    }]
  });
 
  let ordersWithCount = orders.map((o) => {
     let orderWithCount = {};
     orderWithCount = o;
     orderWithCount.count = o.OrderItem.count;
     return orderWithCount;
  });
```